# Are 'a' and 'one' interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles

I know that we can say:

> There is only one car on the lot.

But is it possible to say:

> There is only a car on the lot.

In general, are these two words interchangeable? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are fine—but they don't mean the same thing.

> There is only one car on the lot.

This means that the number of cars on the lot is 1.

> There is only a car on the lot.

This means that there is nothing on the lot *except for* a single car. (No trucks, no people, no carts, and so on.)

---

It's true that in both sentences there is a single car on the lot. That *specific* piece of information is the same. But the overall meaning of each sentence is different.

Answer (score 0):

Etymologically the indefinite article 'an' and the numeral 'one' are the same. 
But in these sentences they differ a little.
The answer to the question 'How many cars are there? is 'There is **one** car...'.
The answer to the question 'Is there anything..?' is 'There is **a** car...'.